# Create MSI to install WPF with registry changes

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, registry, windows-installer

We have a WPF app (.NET 4.0) in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. It needs to add a few registry keys during the installation. How do you add such code to an MSI? If you can point us to an example, it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Use an installer package and tell it what registry keys to create.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterRitchie. Forgive my ignorance: What is an installer package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) to create your MSI. You can create registry values within the WiX project: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/write_a_registry_entry.htm

Answer (score 1):

Use an installer package like InstallShield.  They all support registry keys and values.  For a more complete list of available packages see http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/authoring.htm

Comment: Is InstallShield a paid package?

Comment: Yes, but there are others that aren't.  There's "free" version of Installshield that comes with VS; but it's very limited.  I'm not sure it does registry keys...